# Can Inception V3 work with image size 150x150x3?

Tags: keras, classification

I saw this code on the official keras documentation and I have read the images need to be resized/ scaled prior to feeding to model. Can you please advise?

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

# input size
input_tensor = Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))

model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=input_tensor, weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean by the best way?

Comment: Simple/ easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inception V3 **can work any size of image** as long as your image has 3 channels. Because ImageNet images consist of 3 channels. The reason it can work with any size is that convolutions do not care about image-sizes.  You can use it with also grayscale images with some extra work but I am not sure if it will destroy the network performance etc. For this, you need to set `include_top = False`, otherwise your image size should match with model's defined size, `(299,299,3)`.

You can re-size images with `Lambda` layer. Let's say you have 1024x1024 images:

```
input_images = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1024, 1024, 3))

whatever_this_size = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.resize(x,(150,150),
                     method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))(input_images)

model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=whatever_this_size, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

If you are using TF-Dataset API, you can also do following:

```
your_train_data = your_train_data.map(lambda x, y: (tf.image.resize(x, (150,150), y))
```